# can I set color on all tabs in iTerm2?

Tags: iterm2

I can set the color of one tab in iTerm2 programmatically with the [it2setcolor](https://iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html) shell integration.

```sh
 $ # In the evening I run the dark theme
 $ it2setcolor preset 'AdventureTime'
 $ # In the morning I go back to the light theme
 $ it2setcolor preset 'Light Background'
```

Is there a way I can set all open tabs in one command?
At present I have to go to each tab and run the above command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send a command to **all sessions in a single window** using Broadcast.

Choose **Shell** > **Broadcast Input** > **Broadcast to all panes in all tabs**

or press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>

Now enter a command in any session. It gets broadcasted to all sessions. To turn off,

Choose **Shell** > **Broadcast Input** > **Send input to current session only**

or press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>